# How to filter a model Django and compare against an id

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to filter a model called "CartItem" , that has a field called item , I want to check whether a product id is in this field. each cartitem instance is connected to a cart.id. The product id is taken from a form in templates.

I currently have " {% if cartitem.objects.filter(item_id=product_id).exists %} " in the template, I also tried making an items list in the views.py , to try to use the "if in" statement in the template, based off the "items" contents, the only problem was that when the browser is refreshed the for loop to create this list is not called , it is only called when the user clicks on the "add to cart" button. Hope that makes sense.

at the moment I get an error:
TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Could not parse the remainder: '(item.id=product.id).exists' from 'cartitem.objects.filter(item.id=product.id).exists'

Thanks

models.py

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item        = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    items_cart  = models.ForeignKey('Cart', blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity    = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'item:{} cart:{} quantity:{}'.format(self.item, self.items_cart, self.quantity)
```

views.py

```
def cart_update(request):
    product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(items_cart_id=cart_obj)
    items = [] 
    for item in cart_items:
        items.append(item.item.id)
    print(items)

    if product_id is not None:
        try:
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)

        except Product.DoesNotExist:
            print("Show message to user, product is gone?")
            return redirect("cart:home")
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
        cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(items_cart_id=cart_obj)
        if product_obj in cart_items:
            cart_items.delete(product_obj)
            added = False
        else:
            newitem = CartItem(item=product_obj, items_cart=cart_obj, quantity=1)
            newitem.save()
            added = True
        request.session['cart_items'] = cart_items.count()
        # return redirect(product_obj.get_absolute_url())
        if request.is_ajax(): # Asynchronous JavaScript And XML / JSON
            print("Ajax request")
            json_data = {
                "added": added,
                "removed": not added,
                "cartItemCount": cart_items.count()
            }
            return JsonResponse(json_data, status=200) # HttpResponse
            # return JsonResponse({"message": "Error 400"}, status=400) # Django Rest Framework
    return redirect("cart:home")
```

cart.html

```
<form class='form-product-ajax' method='POST' action='{% url "cart:update" %}' data-endpoint='{% url "cart:update" %}' class="form" {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}data-user='abc'{% endif %}> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}' {% if  product.is_digital %}data-is-digital='true'{% endif %}/>
      <span class='submit-span'>

    {% if cartitem.objects.filter(item_id=product_id).exists %}
        <div class='btn-group'> <a class='btn btn-link' href='/cart/'>In cart</a> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Remove?</button></div>
    {% else %}
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Add to cart</button>
    {% endif %}

    </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not use this syntax in template django:

```py
cartitem.objects.filter(item.id=product.id).exists
```

you can use `templatetags` and call it in your template:

```py
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def existing_product(product):
    return CartItem.objects.filter(item.id=product.id).exists()
```

then load your templatetag in your template

```html
{% load file_name_containing_your_method %}


<form class='form-product-ajax' method='POST' action='{% url "cart:update" %}' data-endpoint='{% url "cart:update" %}' class="form" {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}data-user='abc'{% endif %}> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='{{ product.id }}' {% if  product.is_digital %}data-is-digital='true'{% endif %}/>
      <span class='submit-span'>

    {% if product|existing_product %}
        <div class='btn-group'> <a class='btn btn-link' href='/cart/'>In cart</a> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-link'>Remove?</button></div>
    {% else %}
        <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Add to cart</button>
    {% endif %}

    </span>
</form>
```

hope this can help your second question

NB: you should reboot your server after adding a templatetag

Comment: could you accept it as right answer, thank you